# Does every chosen seed for random.seed() guarantee that random will generate a uniformly distributed sequence?

Tags: python, random, seed

Let's say I would like to generate *n > 10 ^ 20* numbers using *random.seed(SEED)* and *n* subsequent calls to *random.random()*. Is the generated sequence guaranteed to be uniformly distributed regardless of the chosen value of *SEED*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let's say I would like to generate n > 10 ^ 20 numbers

Let's say not.  If you could generate a billion values per second, that would require `1E20 values / 1E9 values per second / 3600 seconds per hour / 24 hours per day / 365.25 days per year`, which is more than 3000 years. Even if you have hardware and energy sources that reliable, you won't be there to see the outcome.

> using random.seed(SEED) and n subsequent calls to random.random()

The results would be statistically indistinguishable from uniform because the underlying algorithm, Mersenne Twister, is designed to produce that behavior.

Comment: @BradSolomon If you re-seed with every call, you effectively are using the PRNG as a hash function of the seed values.  Unless the seed values are themselves i.i.d. uniform (in which case why do you need a PRNG?), there's no telling what distribution the results may have.

Comment: I think I follow you.  But in this case, looping through a 1-step range means you do have uniformly spread seed values, right?  Empirically at least, the result seems to be uniform.  Not that I'm at all condoning re-calling `seed`.

Comment: @BradSolomon Uniformity is not the sole requirement for a PRNG.  You also need to mimic independence.  As an extreme case, the sequence 1,2,3,4,... would be asymptotically uniform but would fail any tests for independence.

Comment: I think that the first part of your answer is irrelevant. But as I get it from the second part, this algorithm produces a uniformly distributed sequence (for a sufficiently large n) for every given seed. This is what I asked to know.

Comment: @Moon I disagree regarding the first part.  I have no idea where you got the idea that it takes ridiculously massive sample sizes to observe uniformity, but that's not so, so what's the point in asking about sample sizes you'll never ever deal with?  Mersenne Twister passes (and fails) the [Diehard test suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) at statistically appropriate rates.